# showing ['and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and'] instead of real values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

when i try to select items from a pandas Series  and or sample list using an other list of indices the output is a list of ['and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and']

i tried to convert the pandaSeries to np.array nothing changed!
used the tolist function nothing!

```
data_list = sample_memo.strip().split() 
data_pandas = pd.Series(data_list) 

def function1(word):

    word_occurance = np.array(data_pandas[data_pandas == word].index)
    next_indexis = (word_occurance+1).tolist()
    next_words = data_pandas[next_indexis].tolist()
    print(next_words)
```

INPUT

```
    word : 'ahead' \n 
    data_pandas   : \n
0           Milt,
1           we're
2           gonna
3            need
4              to
5              go
6           ahead
7             and
8            move
9             you
10     downstairs
11           into
12        storage
13             B.
14             We
15           have
16           some
17            new
18         people
19         coming
20            in,
21            and
22             we
23           need
```

OUTPUT

```
['and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and']
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include (at least a part) of what `data_list` looks like? When you are calling `function1(word)`, what word are you passing to it?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: It looks like you're asking for all the words which follow the word "ahead" in the sample text. Could it be that for all 6 instances of "ahead" in your full text, the word "and" is next?

Comment: well! yes that 's it :) i was expecting another result for another word